# How to integrate react-native-video when using Podfiles to integrate react-native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

In the installation instructions for iOS, it says to run

`react-native link`

After completion I see:

[image]

However, compiling immediately fails with the error React/RCTViewManager.h not found:

[image]

When looking at the [integration instructions on Facebook's website](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html), it has us using a Podfile. When you use a Podfile, your project looks like this:

[image]

Comparing this to the react native sample project, I can see that in fact, it does not appear to use a Podfile to integrate react native at all; instead all React components are included as libraries:

[image]

Thus, I suspect that the integration instructions for react-native-video are not compatible with the [integration instructions found here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html#podfile).

Can anyone suggest how to integrate react-native-video when using Podfiles to integrate react-native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of react native are you using? This looks like it's due to the [breaking change](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.40.0) for RN version >0.40.

The short fix for this issue is if you see `#import React/$(filename)` in the native code, replace it with `#import "$(filename)"`, but if you can update to RN >0.40 that would be preferable.

To answer your question about pods, you should be able to add something like `pod 'react-native-video', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-video'` to your podfile and run `pod install` (if the relative path from your Podfile to the library root is incorrect replace it with the correct one). Looking at the github page for `react-native-video`, it does have a podspec so it *probably* supports cocoapods installation

Comment: Your tip worked -- I needed to add `pod 'react-native-video', :path => 'node_modules/react-native-video'` and I was able to properly integrate this project. I am running react native 0.43. Thanks!